# Hazelcast IMDG json filtering

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to filter json objects inside an array but I'm getting invalid output.

```
HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> departments = hazelCast.getMap("deps");
        departments.put("1",
                new HazelcastJsonValue("{\r\n"
                        + "    \"departmentId\": 1,\r\n"
                        + "    \"room\": \"alpha\",\r\n"
                        + "    \"people\": [\r\n"
                        + "        {\r\n"
                        + "            \"name\": \"Peter\",\r\n"
                        + "            \"age\": 26,\r\n"
                        + "            \"salary\": 50000\r\n"
                        + "        },\r\n"
                        + "        {\r\n"
                        + "            \"name\": \"Jonah\",\r\n"
                        + "            \"age\": 50,\r\n"
                        + "            \"salary\": 140000\r\n"
                        + "        }\r\n"
                        + "    ]\r\n"
                        + "}"));

        Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> departmentWithPeter = departments.values(new SqlPredicate("people[any].name='Peter'"));
        System.err.println(departmentWithPeter.toString());
```

Expected output:-

```
{
    "departmentId": 1,
    "room": "alpha",
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": 26,
            "salary": 50000
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the issue here.
Is there any other functions that supports the json filtration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the output you get is correct. Your query says: "Find all departments that include any person with the name 'Peter'". So you basically query for departments with the condition.

I don't think you can filter the internals of the JSON in such a simple way.

Comment: Is it not possible in Hazelcast IMDG? or Should I write custom java function to do the nested filtration?

Comment: Technically, you can do everything with a custom Aggregator and then execute `departments.aggregate(yourAggregator)`. Check more here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/query/aggregations.html